Where does Holder inequality come in during the proof of Gap statistic?
I am struggling to understand the proof from the Gap-statistic paper (https://hastie.su.domains/Papers/gap.pdf)
However, I am stuck here as shown below. I cannot understand where Holder's inequality comes in from 1st equation to 2nd equation. Any comments are welcomed!

